# Spring forms client side validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, forms

I'm trying to validate a spring form cliënt side. Here for I send an ajax request to my spring controller.

Problem: The ajax call is only executed once, after a second form submission, the call isn't fired anymore. What is the cause of this? Is there a problem in my script? All fields are filled in fine, my controller receives the request, and sends a response the first form submission.

It's like the form won't try to submit anymore after the first try.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                var $form = $('#registratieFormulier');
                $form.bind('submit', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    console.log('submit');
                    var $form = $('#registratieFormulier');
                    // Ajax validation
                    var $inputs = $form.find('input');
                    var data = collectFormData($inputs);

                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url:'<portlet:resourceURL id="valideerFormulier" ></portlet:resourceURL>',
                                data:data,
                                type: 'GET',
                                success: function(response) {
                                    console.log(response);
                                    console.log(response.ajaxResult.status);
                                    if(response.ajaxResult.status == "FAIL") {

                                        } else {

                                        }   
                                }
                            }); 
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            });             
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call e.preventDefault() is what makes it stop working. 
I would bind the code to the click event (not the submit event), then you can submit the form with javascript if validation succeeds or return falls when it fails.